# Why is not Login-AzureRmAccount being persisted in the PowerShell session?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to do some really basic powershell against Azure but the login behaves *weird (?)*.

[image]

Why is not `Login-AzureRmAccount` being persisted in the PowerShell session?

**Edit:**
Trying to re-install the AzureRM module yields the following result:
[image]

Comment: I suspect you need to update powershell modules, `Install-Module -Force AzureRM`

Comment: I tried that and updated the question. Still fails.

Comment: What is the version of AzureRM.profile running on your PowerShell?

Comment: Try with the latest version: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.profile/2.5.0

Comment: 2.5.0 (which seem to be the latest available) @juvchan

Comment: Have you tried the same in PowerShell ISE?

Comment: try updating powershell version? running `Install-Module -Force AzureRM -AllowClobber`? `/sfc scannow`? Something is wrong with your particular powershell, not with module or powershell in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So finally I found the solution to my problem:**

`Install-Module AzureRm -AllowClobber`

---

I also tried `sfc scannow` but that didn't work. It just said there were no problems.
`Install-Module AzureRm -Force` didnt work either.

At first I didn't want to run `-AllowClobber` but after reading up on http://adamringenberg.com/powershell2/tag/allowclobber/ it didnt sound *that* bad so I gave it a shot.